# Network Monitoring - Windows Server 2008 r2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, monitoring, usage

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 R2.
It's set up as a DHCP and DNS server, with RRAS, Hyper-V, RDP, IIS (Apache server, MySQL, FTP) and a few game servers.
Three NICs, one out to the WAN, one into the LAN and one dedicated to Hyper-V out to the WAN.

What I want is a nice tool with a GUI which will enable me to monitor network traffic and usage. Specifically, one which will monitor usage on each NIC and a breakdown of the traffic (by local client, application etc.)
Preferably, with the option to export the data to xls.

From a bit of research and a few searches, there's plenty of options, but I want to get some opinions and suggestions on what to use.

Cheers,
Mick.

Comment: This question really belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/faq).

Comment: Tried there, no joy and was closed off by the admins.

Comment: @NathanC Shopping or product recommendation questions are off topic everywhere, not just here. Don't send people to [su] with things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard really is [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Check it out.